# Conditional Expectation of Sum of Squared Normals Given Ratio

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I have the following problem: Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be independent random variables with standard normal distribution. Compute $E(X_1^2+X_2^2 | Y),$ where $Y=X_1/X_2$.

I have avoided brute forcing it and instead apply Proposition 1.9 of Shao, which states: Let $X$ and $Y$ be random vectors and suppose $(X,Y)$ has joint p.d.f. $f(x,y)$ w.r.t. $\nu\times\lambda$, where $\nu$ and $\lambda$ are two $\sigma$-finite measures on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$. If $g(x,y)$ is a Borel function for which $Eg(X,Y)<\infty$, then $$E[g(X,Y) | Y] =\frac{\int g(x,Y)f(x,Y)d\nu(x)}{\int f(x,Y)d\nu(x)},$$ almost surely.

However, I have not gotten it to work. Any pointers?

Comment: Hint: Show that $X_1^2+X_2^2$ and $Y$ are independent. Sub-hint: think polar coordinates. (The sub-hint was already given by user @JohnDawkins in a now deleted answer.)

Comment: Hmm, I was able to show that the joint p.d.f. of $Z:=X^2_1+X^2_2$ and $Y$ is geven by $f_{Z,Y}=\frac{2}{\pi}(e^{-3/2})\frac{1}{y^2+1},$ from which we may conclude $Z$ and $Y$ are independent since $Y$ has the Gamma distribution. This then shows $Z$ has the gamma distribution and so $E[Z|Y]=E[Z]=3/4$. I am having some trouble with this solution since intuitively I thought $Z$ would follow $X^2$-distribution. More confusing is your sub-hint, haha.

Comment: $\chi^2$, not $X^2$..

Comment: You might want to check what the $\chi^2(2)$ distribution reduces to.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for your help.